# Load title and header HTML by URL

Tags: 7, views

I'm using drupal 7 and I want to load the view title and header HTML of this view by Its URL. Is IT possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a direct function that I'm aware of. But you can query the `views_display` DB table, indirectly to retrieve your view as the path data is serialized information:

```
function get_view_from_path($path) {
  $page_views = db_select('views_display','vd');
  $page_views->join('views_view', 'vv', 'vv.vid = vd.vid');
  $page_views = $page_views->fields('vd')
    ->fields('vv')
    ->condition('display_plugin', 'page')
    ->execute();

  foreach ($page_views as $view) {
    $options = unserialize($view->display_options);
    if ($options['path'] == $path) {
      return views_get_view($view->name);
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

if ($my_view = get_view_from_path('my-view-path')) {
  // @TODO: Look @ $my_view->display["page"]->display_title
  // $my_view->display["page"]->display_options['header']
  // for title & header data.
}
```